# Get method from extern/second file in c# in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to get make methods in another file to then call them to the mainfile, it's the first time I'm trying this and I don't know what goes wrong.

I have named the class in the second method `SecondClass` and the method `Second`. Then in the mainfile I wrote `SecondClass.Second();`.

This is my code in the main file:

```
using System;

namespace uppdrag_2.cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Menu choices
            string[] menuOptions = new string[] {"New customer\t", "New staff\t", "Serivce\t", "Reparation", "Garantie", "End program"};
            int menuSelect = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.CursorVisible = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome! Please choose type of registration:");

                if (menuSelect == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[0] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[5]);
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[1] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[5]);
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[2] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[5]);
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[3] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[5]);
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[4] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[5]);
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[4]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[5] + "<--");
                } 
                var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && menuSelect != menuOptions.Length - 1)
                {
                    menuSelect++;
                }
                else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && menuSelect >= 1)
                {
                    menuSelect--;
                } 
                else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    switch (menuSelect)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            Newcustomer();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            NewStaff();
                                break;
                        case 2:
                            Service();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Reparation();
                                break;
                        case 4:
                            Garantie();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            EndProgram();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Newcustomer(){
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to registrate a new customer!");
            Console.Clear();

            //Here I can`t reach the method from the other file
            SecondClass.Second();
            Console.Clear();

        }
        public static void NewStaff(){
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to registrer a new staffmember!");
            Console.Clear();

        }
        public static void Service(){
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to register a service matter!");
            Console.Clear();

        }
        public static void Reparation(){
            Console.WriteLine("You have choosen to registrer a reparation matter!");
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void Garantie(){
            Console.WriteLine("You have choosen to registrate a garantie matter!");
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void EndProgram(){
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to end the program! \nPress Enter to end...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        
        }
    }
```

This is my code in the second file:

```
using System;

namespace uppdrag_2.cs
{
    public static class SecondClass
    {
        public static void Second()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("utskrift från andra filen");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Kind regrads Johanna

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: FYI a namespace usually does not have ". cs"

Comment: From your text, you seem to call that Second method correctly (too much code in the first block to look for it there). So what happened? Compile time error, runtime exception? Then please show the exact message. Did something unexpected (not) happen? Then please state what you expected and what did happen

Comment: Are these classes/files inside one Visual Studio project?

Comment: Okay I`m sorry now I`ve tried to deleate som code to make it easier to read, I hope its more clear now!

Comment: Okay! is it wrong to write .cs or that I shoulnd`t have it with namespace for some reason? ( it was what was showed when I created the main file)

Comment: It sais "The name `SecondClass` does not exist in the current context" and I cant run the code

Comment: Hans Kesting, I think so, I created a new file when I was in  a Visual studio project and it seems to be within the same project. It dosent say that the method "Second" does not exist even though I created it in the other file, but it says that the class dosen`t  exist "The name `SecondClass` doese not exist in the current context"

Comment: It is not *wrong* to have `namespace uppdrag_2.cs`, but it means just that this is the "cs" sub-namespace in the main "uppdrag_2" namespace. The "cs" doesn't mean anything special (as in "related to C#"), it doesn't refer to some file name, it is just a name to group your classes

Comment: Is that `SecondClass` class defined in a file SecondClass.cs (note the important .cs extension)? Instead of adding a new "file", use the Solution Explorer to add a new *class* (then it will get the correct extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the problem "The name ‘SecondClass' does not exist in the current context", you could try the following steps to solve it.

[image]

First, we have to click on ‘Show potential fixes’ and then choose “Generate class ‘SecondClass’ in new file”.

[image]

Second, we will get a new file called ‘SecondClass.cs’.

[image]

Finally, we just need to copy the code into the new file.

[image]

In summary, the code in the main file will not report errors any more.

[image]